Pass reference argument to STL container element constructor
Very often in C++ I want an STL container of a type which has a reference member:
struct C {};

struct S
{
    S() = default;

    S(const C& c) : _c(c)
    {}

    const C& _c;   // I always have to use a pointer here
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    std::array<S, 10> arr{ c };   // Can c be passed here?

    return 0;
}

However, because references have to be set from the beginning, I can never get this to work and have to use a pointer (which I really dislike).
The above doesn't compile.
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'S'

Is it possible to pass the reference in via the std::array's constructor and avoid using a pointer?

You may be interested in the std::reference_wrapper and the associated helper function std::ref.

S() = default; is "wrong" (is actually deleted).

With correct number of initializer, it works Demo.

Reference member make the class non-default constructible and lost also some other properties, making the class harder to use.

Why not use a pointer member?

@Jarod42 Is there an elegant way to implement your solution for 1,000 array elements?

std::array<S, 1000> arr{c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c, keep repeating c, to fill out all 1000 elements is the elegant solution.

Write a make_array See another answer. Notice you will have to call it with S{c}.


Is it possible to pass the reference in via the std::array's constructor and avoid using a pointer?
[...] keep repeating c, how to fill out all 1000 elements is the elegant solution?

If you do not like the pointers, I would suggest using the std::reference_wrapper instead of plane references. Why:

What is the difference between std::reference_wrapper and a simple pointer?

Benefits of using reference_wrapper instead of raw pointer in containers?


#include <functional> // std::reference_wrapper

struct S
{
    constexpr explicit S(C& c) 
        : _c{c} {}

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<C> _c;
};

Now, to fill the array, (in C++20) you could write a helper make_ref_array() as follows:
template <size_t N>
constexpr auto make_ref_array(C& refArg)
{
    return [&refArg]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::array<S, sizeof...(Is)>{(static_cast<void>(Is), S{ refArg })...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

so that, the array creation be like
C c;
auto arr = make_ref_array<100u>(c);

See a live demo
Now, it can be more generic as:
template <typename T, size_t N, typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_ref_array(Args&... args)
{
    return []<size_t... Is, typename... Ts>(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&... ts) {
        return std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>{(static_cast<void>(Is), T{ ts... })...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, args...);
}

Note that, all the args will be referenced to construct the T, even if the other data members are not references.

For the compilers older than C++20, the template lambda must be moved to a separate template function as like in this example

Thank you for this. I'm just..... bemused why C++ cannot do this under the hood. When someone writes std::array<S, 1000> arr{c}; they obviously want c passed to all 1000 elements! Nobody initializes just one element of an array.

There are 2 issues in your code:

You cannot make the default constructor defaulted with:
S() = default;

Because the reference of the_c member must be initialized.

arr should be initialized with 10 elements (because S cannot be default constructed as explained above):
std::array<S, 10> arr{c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c};



Demo

From the example given you may want to make _c static. (Also rename to not have the underscore as anything beginning with _ variables are reserved for the standard library.)
If not you are probably looking for:
 std::array<S, 10> array{S{c}};

Here 10 Ss are constructed from the same c

Making S::c static would force to initialize it before main... And would change the semantic of the class.

S{c} was unneeded, S(const C&) is implicit. But It would construct only the first element, issue is with the other 9 objects, which cannot be default-initialized.

Changing c to static is a design change. There's nothing in the question to indicate that this is appropriate.

Also rename to not have the underscore as anything beginning with _ variables are reserved for the standard library. is incorrect.  Only at the global scope is that true.  At any scope, starting with _ followed by uppercase is reserved; _ followed by lowercase is not reserved and may be used freely (outside of the global scope).  Also, double-underscare __ anywhere in an identifier is also reserved, at any scope.

No, names beginning with an underscore are not reserved for the standard library. Name that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Names that begin with an underscore followed by a lowercase letter are reserved for use by the implementation in global scope. There's nothing wrong (other than looking silly ) with using them in block scope.
